# WinUI 3 TreeView - How to add selection on right click

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, winui

I am trying to show a MenuFlyout on a WinUI 3 TreeView when the user right clicks on a node, and allow them to choose an action that applies to the node. Single node selection is in effect, and the node is not automatically selected on a right click.

After searching, I came across [this answer](https://help.syncfusion.com/winui/treeview/selection#how-to-add-selection-on-right-click), but it doesn't work with WinUI 3, because the [WinUI 3 TreeView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.Controls.TreeView?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) does not have a `GetNodeAt` method, I don't see how to get a TreeViewNode from a point.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CommandBarFlyout
            x:Name="TestCommanBarFlyout"
            Placement="Right">
            <AppBarButton Icon="Copy" />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" />
        </CommandBarFlyout>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                <TreeViewItem
                    Content="{x:Bind}"
                    ContextRequested="TreeViewItem_ContextRequested" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new() { "A", "B", "C" };

private void TreeViewItem_ContextRequested(UIElement sender, ContextRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (sender is TreeViewItem item)
    {
        item.IsSelected = true;
        TestCommanBarFlyout.ShowAt(
            item,
            new FlyoutShowOptions()
            {
                ShowMode = FlyoutShowMode.Standard
            });
    }
}
```