How to switch `ContextFlyout` on `DataTemplate` based on properties of the bound type?
Let’s say I have a ListView, a DataTemplate for the items and two MenuFlyouts:
<Page>
    <Page.Resources>
        <MenuFlyout x:Key="Menu1" />
        <MenuFlyout x:Key="Menu2" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template"
                      x:DataType="local:MyItem">
            <TreeViewItem>
                <Grid ContextFlyout="{StaticResource Menu1}">
                </Grid>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    <TreeViewItem
    </Page.Resources>
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template}"
              Items="{x:Bind ...}"
</Page>

So each item in the ListView has a context/right-click menu set to Menu1.
Now, let's say I want to have a different context menu for some of the items in the ListView, e.g., Menu2. How can I accomplish this?
In other words, how do I switch the ContextFlyout to MenuFlyout Menu2 for certain MyItem items in the ListView based on values of properties in the MyItem type?
Update, Clarification
I wasn't specifying the question completely. Obviously, to accomplish that you would bind the to the ContextFlyout. This was not my question.
In my case I cannot do that because:

The view model provide the items that are bound to the ItemSource of a ListView/TreeView/etc,
but the view models reside in a platform independent library/project, i.e., there should be no references to platform dependent UI code, such as WinAppSDK.

So I need to find a way in the UI layer to hook in to each item provided by the view model and then set the ContextMenu based on the properties of that item.
The question becomes: how to, in the UI layer (e.g., a Page or its code behind), change a value (which is not bound to the view model, it's a resource in the UI layer) within a DataTemplate, based on the current bound item?
I've also looked at ContextRequested but the docs recommend setting the ContextFlyout property instead.
I hope this makes my question clearer.
Possible Solution
The only way I can think of how to do it is in a DataTemplateSelector:
<MenuFlyout x:Key="MenuFlyout1">
    <MenuFlyoutItem Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.Command1}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                    Text="1">
    </MenuFlyoutItem>
</MenuFlyout>

<MenuFlyout x:Key="MenuFlyout2">
    <MenuFlyoutItem Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.Command2}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                    Text="2">
    </MenuFlyoutItem>
</MenuFlyout>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate"
              x:DataType="local:MyItem">
    <TreeViewItem />
</DataTemplate>

<local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="Selector"
                          MenuFlyout1="{StaticResource MenuFlyout1}"
                          MenuFlyout2="{StaticResource MenuFlyout2}"
                          MyDataTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />

public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public MyDataTemplate Template { get; set; } = null!;
    public MenuFlyout MenuFlyout1 { get; set; } = null!;
    public MenuFlyout MenuFlyout2 { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override DataTemplate? SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        MenuFlyout menuToUse;
        if (item.Type == 1)
            menu = MenuFlyout1;        
        else 
            menu = MenuFlyout2;   
     
        // How to assign menu to `Template` ?

        return Template;
    }
}

But I cannot manage to assign the menu to the Template. It've tried
var treeViewItem = Template.GetElement(new());
treeViewItem.ContextFlyout = MenuFlyout1;

but it has no effect.

To reuse a DataTemplate, make the DataTemplate as resource in ResourceDictionary. See Resource dictionaries with {x:Bind} for more information. Then for changing the ContextFlyout based on the Type, make it refer to a global resource key or  x:Bind to a MyItem 's property.

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT What do you mean by make it refer to a global resource key? How can I then change the key based on the type? (I cannot do the seond alt since MyItem resides in the view model layer so I don't want any ui dependencies in there.)

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT Also when I create a reusable DataTemplate according to the link, I keep getting "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
" when running. There's no stack trace or no other info.

I can make Resource dictionaries with {x:Bind} work and cannot override the resource key but you can get a workaround from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1465387/generic-xaml-x-bind-with-converter-binding.
TemplatesResourceDictionary.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="App1.TemplatesResourceDictionary"
    xmlns:local="using:App1">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="EmployeeTemplate" x:DataType="local:IEmployee">
        <Grid Background="{x:Bind Color}">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Foreground="{StaticResource MyBrush}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>

TemplatesResourceDictionary.xaml.cs
namespace App1
{
    public partial class TemplatesResourceDictionary
    {
        public TemplatesResourceDictionary()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

IEmployee
class IEmployee
{
    public IEmployee(string n, Brush b)
    {
        Name = n;
        Color = b;
    }
    public string Name;
    public Brush Color;
}

App.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application
    x:Class="App1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Red" />
            
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->
                <local:TemplatesResourceDictionary/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Other app resources here -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

MainWindow.xaml
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="MyBrush">Black</Color>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Employees}" ItemTemplate ="{StaticResource EmployeeTemplate}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="MyBrush">Green</Color>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Employees}" ItemTemplate ="{StaticResource EmployeeTemplate}">
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>



Thank you for the elaborate answer. I've managed to get it working using ResourceDictionary with x:Bind. However, this was not my intended question. I have tried to clarify the question. Please see the updated question. My apologies.

@Karmeye DataTemplateSelector is a proper solution.

Thank you for indicating the proper solution. I still cannot figure out how to assign the menu to the template instance. Please see my updated question under the Possible Solution header.

@Karmeye why not use two separate DataTemplates with different ContextFlyout? Otherwise, you need to change the selected TreeViewItem instance 's ContextFlyout like the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74146531.

That’s what I’m hoping to avoid. It’s the sole reason I asked this question.
Imagine a quite complex structure of almost 100 lines, you don’t want to duplicate that to bloat your XAML and make it delicate as soon as you want to change something. And I actually need more than two. Furthermore, there might be other things than ContextFlyout I want to change in the same manner; font weight for example.  I was hoping I could change things in the DataTemplateSelector. I wish there was a way to derive from DataTemplate like there is with Style's BasedOn.
